# Classifying topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to produce a diagram which illustrates the relationships between different topological spaces; from the 'simplest' to the increasingly more structured. However, I'm not certain about some of the relationships. I've seen similar diagrams on various websites but they typically only mention three or four spaces. I'm particularly interested in how Riemannian manifolds fit into the puzzle. Also, casual interchangeability of 'space' and 'manifold' which some people use has created some confusion.

Currently the diagram has the following structure (I hope its visible):

[image]

I'm almost certain some of these relationship are incorrect as I don't have the technical background to fully understand it all. If anyone is able to say outright that a particular part of the diagram is incorrect (or correct) I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions for correcting it.

Comment: Any Hilbert space is also a Banach space.

Comment: Does that mean that an inner-product space is also a Banach space?

Comment: No, because they need not be complete. An inner product space is a normed vector space.